# What is meant by sandboxing?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, html5, browser

Sanboxing is listed as one of the many security features in html5 specification . Can someone explain what is meant by sandboxing? Does it relate to HTML only or to JavaScript also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sandboxing means running an application in containment, seperate from outside applications. This way, the application is cut-off from anything that it may want to do something malicious to. Specifically in this context, your browser will try to sandbox the JS on a page to ensure it doesn't affect more than what it's supposed to.